# Why am I posting another Riley?

Tags: riddle

I’m aggressive, astute if you will,
My middle and end, will make you go still,
But my end alone, rituals fulfil,
My start is deep, but not used anymore,
Now find out what I am, that’s what I ask for.

Hint:

> The title isn’t a hint I’m just actually confused why I continue posting these

Comment: Yeah, I posted my last Riley Riddle today, actually :P

Comment: Last? Wow that’s a big promise

Answer (score 3):

I think the answer is

> Pitstop

I’m aggressive, astute if you will

> During a motor race, pitstops are used strategically to try and increase a driver's chance of winning. The timing and number of pitstops taken in a race requires astute decision-making. Refuelling, changing of tyres and other actions are usually performed as quickly as possible so are often aggressive in their undertaking.

My middle and end, will make you go still,

> Stop

But my end alone, rituals fulfil,

> Top - *practice makes perfect*

My start is deep, but not used anymore,

> Pit - pits are often very deep (e.g, a coal mine). I think the type of pit not used anymore might be referring to an enclosure in which animals are made to fight (e.g, a bear pit).

Now find out what I am, that’s what I ask for.

> Pitstop

Answer (score 0):

How about

> well-bred?

I’m aggressive, astute if you will,

> Not sure, but astuteness *could* result from good pedigree.

My middle and end, will make you go still,

> Coldness, denoted by **br**, has a chilling effect. And **red** is the traffic light color that tells you to stop.

But my end alone, rituals fulfil,

> The ending **ed** could be an abbreviation for "education", which, when formalized, is often only achieved by the completion of ritualized acts.

My start is deep, but not used anymore,

> **Well**s are not nearly as common for individuals to use for accessing water [now](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_water_supply_and_sanitation#Modern_age) as they were in the past.

Comment: Can you explain "*my end alone, rituals fulfil*" ?

Comment: @Evargalo I was least sure about that one, but I edited in my best effort.

Answer (score -1):

I think you're

> A stop sign

I’m aggressive, astute if you will,

> you tell drivers what to do

My middle and end, will make you go still,

> The end is the sign itself, the middle is a pole which can also be used to

But my end alone, rituals fulfil,

> stop, look and go

My start is deep, but not used anymore,

> it's in the ground

Now find out what I am, that’s what I ask for.

> here you go?